# there any way to implement this controller, but instead find a .json find a .html, to change dynamically this templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

there any way to implement this controller, but instead find a .json find a .html, to change dynamically this templateUrl (sorry for my bad English):

```js
.when('/news/:itemId',{
        templateUrl: 'this template',
        controller: 'ItemDetailCtrl',
        title: 'Artículo'
      })

.controller('ItemDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $http.get('json/news/' + $routeParams.itemId + '.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.item = data;
    });
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use templateUrl as a function. It takes the parameters as argument and should return a string.

```
.when('/news/:itemId',{
  templateUrl: function(params) {
    //Do some stuff and return templateURL
    return 'json/news/' + params.itemId + '.json'
  },
  controller: 'ItemDetailCtrl',
  title: 'Artículo'
})
```

I'm not sure if it works with *.json, thoug.

Here's the documentation of `.when`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider#when